# How to reduce Google Login API consent request to below "See, edit, download, and permanently delete your contacts"

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I'm integrating my site with Google Login API (Sign in with Google) thingy and when someone tries to login via their Google account, they need to allow my site to "See, edit, download, and permanently delete your contacts".

Delete contacts sounds very scary to most people, so how can I reduce the scope? I only need the user's profile and email, NOT their contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Scope(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY)` instead of `Scope(PeopleServiceScopes.CONTACTS)` , and avoid using `Scope("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/")` ([here](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/)) .

Example of what you can use:

```
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestServerAuthCode(...)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_ADDRESSES_READ),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USERINFO_PROFILE),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_BIRTHDAY_READ),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_EMAILS_READ),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USERINFO_EMAIL),
                    Scope(PeopleScopes.USER_PHONENUMBERS_READ))
            .build()
```

And the result:

[image]